# youtube embedded url setting not making the video autoplay

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

i want a youtube embedded video to autoplay once loaded but using this after the video url doesnt seem to work
`?autoplay=1&loop=1&autopause=0&muted=1`

I am displaying the video that is retrieved from user input in an iframe as follow

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/${videoId}?autoplay=1&loop=1&autopause=0&muted=1" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>`
```

also i have a function that gets the videoId

```
function getId(url) {
    const regExp = /^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|&v=)([^#&?]*).*/;
    const match = url.match(regExp);

    return (match && match[2].length === 11) ?
        match[2] :
        null;
}
```

the video is correctly displayed but doesn't automatically start. I dont know which part of the code is causing this issue

Comment: please remove the muted = 1 to mute=1. working example https://jsfiddle.net/nishantj/36ge4vtL/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not starting because of `muted=1` param - it should be **`mute=1`**.